# Autocomplete return blank if the current value is not on the list

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

My code works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/qv94t/7/. But when the option value is came from by php the function is not working properly. I used ajax for generating the option value, but it has also the same error if I echo the option value in the same page and not using ajax.

Why is that? Help please

My ajax

**getajax.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["mainlist_id"])) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015");
    $main = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["mainlist_id"]);


$result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM code WHERE cat_code='$main' GROUP BY item_code ORDER BY item");

    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
    {
    ?>
    <option class="eachop" value ="<?php echo $row['item'];?>"><?php echo $row['item'];?></option>';
<?php
    }
    }
?>
```

And here's my full code, I forgot to add my ajax and dropdown. Someone help please?

**ajax.php**

```
 <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015");
    $combo = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM category GROUP BY cat_code ORDER BY id");
    $option = '';
     while($row = $combo->fetch_assoc())
        {
        $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['cat_code'].'">'.$row['category'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
<select id="main" name="main">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
<input list="languages" id="none"></input>
<datalist id="languages" name="options">
    <option value=""></option>
</datalist>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#main').change(function(){
$.ajax({
url : 'getajax.php',
data :{mainlist_id : $(this).val()},
dataType:'html',
type:'POST',
success:function(data){
$('#languages').html(data);
}
});
});
</script>
<script>
    var validOptions = [];
    $("option").each(function () {
        validOptions.push($(this).val())
    });
    previousValue = "";
    console.log(validOptions)
    $('#none').autocomplete({
        autoFocus: true,
        source: validOptions
    }).keyup(function () {
        var isValid = false;
        for (i in validOptions) {
            if (validOptions[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
                isValid = true;
            }
        }
        if (!isValid) {
            this.value = previousValue
        } else {
            previousValue = this.value;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: how you generating  $option in php ?? can you share your page source when viewed by browser

Comment: @CodingAnt I updated my question. Actually It's generate by ajax. I just post like that bcoz It has a same error.

Comment: I think your last script is executed before ajax operation is completed. However, it's hard to tell what is wrong without seeing how are you generating `$option` with ajax (I mean where, when).

Comment: @user3280126 I put my ajax. Please take a look. Even if without using ajax, the error still the same.

Comment: Considering `ajax.php`, is your `$option` variable created correctly? I mean, just before echoing, is `$option` as you expected?

Comment: @user3280126 It works correctly. I used that in field main dropdown to display my category and send the value of it in ajax.

Comment: @user3280126 I updated my question I put my full code. Hope you can help me with this. Please

Comment: One last question, In `getajax.php`, is your query returning results or furthermore, are you generating options true? I can't see any problem, sorry. You are doing it in right way in `ajax.php`. I suggest you to put error callback to your jquery ajax call and check if script is executed without error or not on browser console.

Comment: @user3280126 There's no problem in getting value in php. The real problem is why my option value is not allowed when it came from php? In normal html my jquery works.

Answer (score 0):

you must **echo** the value then only, ajax get the value and displayed use below code....

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST["mainlist_id"])) {
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015");
        $main = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["mainlist_id"]);


    $result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM code WHERE cat_code='$main' GROUP BY item_code ORDER BY item");

        while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
        { 
        echo "<option class=\"eachop\" value =\"".$row['item']."\">".$row['item']."</option>";
        }
     }
    ?>
```